# Add OrderByDescending to Linq statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-order-by

I've got the following code to extract keywords from a string:

```
var results = text.Split(new char[]{' ',',','.','!','?','_',':',';','/','(',')','\n','\r','-','*','"','/','\\','$','%','+','-','='})               // default split by whitespace
    .GroupBy(str => str)  // group words by the value
    .Select(g => new
                 {
                     str = g.Key,      // the value
                     count = g.Count() // the count of that value
                 });
```

Now I need to add `OrderByDescending` to it, but not sure where to place it. 
`.GroupBy(str => str).OrderByDescending(count => count)` yielded incorrect results. How to make it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it after the select.

```
.Select(...whatever...).OrderByDescending(item => item.count);
```

Comment: +1 for better performance. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088064/add-orderbydescending-to-linq-statement/4088088#4088088) for an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use it after the GroupBy and call `g.Count()` the same way you did in your `Select` statement:

```
.GroupBy(str => str)
.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
.Select(g => new ...) // rest of your code here
```

EDIT: I actually prefer [Anthony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088064/add-orderbydescending-to-linq-statement/4088098#4088098) to my own and was about to modify mine but by then he had posted his response. It's a very minor concern and is a premature optimization, but my posted approach will be slightly slower when dealing with large collections since `Count()` is being executed twice, whereas Anthony's approach is sorting on the already computed `Count()` made in the `Select` statement. Just something to keep in mind when constructing clean LINQ queries.

As an aside, in query syntax we can get around this by storing the count in a `let` (sure, this is possible in fluent syntax but feels more natural in query syntax) which would provide good performance. Something like this:

```
var query = from g in text.Split(...).GroupBy(str => str)
            let count = g.Count()
            orderby count descending
            select new { str = g.Key, Count = count };
```

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding is due to the fact that you give the variable in the lambda the same name as a property on the anonymous type. The `OrderByDescending(count => count)` sorts on the whole object. What you want is to sort on the count-property, so you should use `OrderByDescending(x => x.count)`.